# Is stream_socket_server in PHP for creating a production server?

Tags: php, sockets

Is stream_socket_server a server for testing, or is it also meant for production?

Is it for making your own *Production* http (or whatever) server, so you don't need Apache or IIS, etc.?

Comment: Do you realize that this is to handle a direct connection that would need to be run in the back-end independently from the web server?  There are multiple ways to proxy and load balance connections but `nginx` seems irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @JuliePelletier nginx was an example of a proxy server for the question.  No.  I did not know that.  I saw that reactPHP seemed to use it as a regular server like a WSGI Python server.  I have removed that part of the question.

Comment: Why not? It's just one of socket functions. You probably don't want your server to be written in php by other reasons, but there is nothing wrong with `stream_socket_server` itself.

Comment: That is a wrapper around tcp/ip sockets. That is part of `networking` i.e. how separate processes communicate with each other. the `server` part of the name just means something that sits and waits for a connection from the network. It has _nothing to do with web servers / HTTP protocols_ etc. You have to write all the code to process the message sent to it. It has no intelligence at all. It is just a network connection waiting for you to connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stream_socket_server` is stable if that's what you're wondering.  The decision to use it in production to replace existing server solutions such as Apache, Nginx or any other will depend on the quality of tests your run on your solution that uses it.

As with any other project, you start with unit testing, checking if each expected functionality works and look for edge cases, then move it to system testing which implies testing more complete solutions.  Once your system tests produce stable results for everyone, you could normally release it in alpha or beta state to encourage user feedback.

After your application has been used by enough people (you decide your thresholds) and there are no more important bug reports open, you can decide to release it in an actual production environment.

That whole process, even in popular applications, can take years.  Some applications remain in beta testing for their whole lifetime.

Note that projects such as Nginx and Apache have had centuries (probably millennials) of developer efforts put into them to make them as flexible and stable as they are today.